# Why my powershell script does not detect dll from dll.refresh file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, powershell, msbuild

I am working on a legacy .Net website project and this project does not contain a References node and .csproj file. This project has a bin folder that contains foo.dll.refresh with the path to foo.dll

If I execute powershell script to build my project, script is not able to copy foo.dll to the bin folder and throwing below error.

```
Exception in MSBuild command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "c:\abc.sln" Configuration=Debug :Build message:   c:\abc\welcome.aspx.cs(7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'foo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [c:abc.metaproj]
```

But when I just open the solution from VS, the dll is getting copied to the bin folder. If I run the Powershell script, it is executing successfully.

what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Try running script by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: I am executing the script as Admin only.

Comment: How did you add the dll?  The right way is using menu Project : Add Existing Item.  Then browse to the source where dll project is found and get dll from the debug folder. The dll may need to get recompiled.  Just dropping a dll into the bin folder will not recompile the dll.  I suspect some references are missing that the dll need to execute.

Comment: I added my dll by right clicking on the project -> Add reference.

Comment: Does file c:\abc\welcome.aspx.cs exist?  Do you have permission to access the file?

Comment: yes file exists and has permission to access this file.

Comment: @jdweng Now I reworded my question with specific details of the issue.

Comment: Do a search on you machine and see if you have other copies of MSBuild.exe.  You are running a X86 version of the executable.  I would delete the abc.sln file.  The open Visual Studio using the csproj (double click) and rebuild the application.  VS should create a new sln file.  You may be using a bad sln.

Comment: I will not have .csproj file as it is .Net WebSite project not a .Net WebApplication project.